# Upgrading from PHP 5.3.3 to PHP 5.5 CentOS 6.9 (Remi-release) WordPress SMF php-mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, centos6

I wanted to upgrade my CentOS 6.9 Server from PHP 5.3.3 to 5.5.38 via remi repo it all worked well and I also get PHP 5.5.38 when I type in "php -v" but now that I am on that version I can't use any MySQL on my Site anymore, the new php-mysql Package is installed but its now called php-mysqlnd.

I already fixed all my MySQL 5.5 Errors by doing mysql_upgrade -u root -p
and resetting the password but it still won't work 
It's a VZ Server. And I have the Parallels Power Panel but not the Plesk Panel
I also restarted mysqld and apache2 (httpd) I even tried apachectl vs. service httpd but I still don't get a working php-mysql on my Server

Adresses BLOCKED-IP - letoria.net (The Domain is a cached Cloudflare Site)
I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Worpdress installation, but not yet - you don't really want to be doing that at the same time as all the other changes. For now, get your current system back running by adding a mysql extension shim (I quite like the one at https://www.dotpointer.tk/mysql/) as an [auto-prepend](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

Comment: Eh so I just wanted to follow the steps and when I put <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> into a PHP file it states that it is still on Version 5.3.3